# Will I detect any signal if I apply laser light on one of the two light sensors placed in a sunlight?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-analysis, sensor, light-sensor

I am trying to make a counter which should work in a solar light. I am thinking to use two ambient light sensors placed close to each other and use a differential amplifier. One sensor receives a RED laser light and sunlight on it. The Second sensor receives just sun-light. Therefore, I would have zero volts at the output if LASER is absent or else HIGH volts if it is present. Will this work?

**EDIT:**

I have two lasers with me. (1) Red laser. 660 nm and 130mW. (2) Green laser 532nm and 50mW.

I have this sensor: http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/ALS-PDIC144-6C-L378.pdf  (also have 5mm too)

Comment: By the way - where possible when adding details, it's best to edit your question rather than adding details as comments - stack exchange works better that way for everyone. (Just don't **change** what you're asking if that makes sense).

Comment: @Jodes Sure. I will update the question once I have more details or circuit diagram on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work, assuming the sensors are well matched. Allow for some leeway. Eg require the signal to reach a minimum difference between the sensors before outputting HIGH. If you give more info, eg purpose of system, what's driving /controlling the laser, and that your final output is used for, I could help with a circuit.

You may be able to avoid needing two sensors if you encode the laser, or at least pulse it. For example, have it pulse at 1kHz (assuming your sensors react fast enough). Then filter out signals below that, then smooth that result and add a schmitt trigger for your final logic signal. This is the idea behind how IR remote control receivers block out ambient light from interfering. The underlying frequency, eg 1kHz is called the carrier frequency.

Either way, using a light filter which blocks everything but the laser light colour could help.

Edit: I found this circuit [from here](http://www.discovercircuits.com/H-Corner/40khzlight.htm) which looks near perfect:

[image]

As per my comment, just ignore the components after the final op-amp and feed into the MCU instead. Then just change a few values to change the reception frequency (currently 40kHz).

Comment: Okay. How can I filter out the signals using the circuits and/or Arduino? I am just applying directly 9 volts to 5 volts buck converter and then the laser. It is rated at 4-5.5 volts. I have a thick beam red laser. I also have a green laser.

Comment: High pass for 1 kHz should work? I have Radioshack ambient sensors to work with. I also have photodiode and IR LED.

Comment: Not necessarily. Sensor reception circuitry needs to be biased such that it does not swamp with the ambient light. If it's already at the rail, no added laser light will make any difference. Modulated or not.

Comment: Ambient sensors are highly unlikely to react fast enough (although I don't know about Radio Shack's). Photodiodes should work well though. Yes, a high pass at about same frequency as laser modulation, plus a bit. Perhaps 100Hz or lower might help if the photodiode or laser circuitry aren't reacting fast enough. If the laser is more than 1mW then it should easily be bright enough.

Comment: @Trevor What kind of sensor reception circuitry do you prefer here? I have tried voltage divider and differential op-amp circuit.

Comment: @Jodes The laser module is 50mW so it should be fine. But, as per the frequency response diagram of the EverLight light sensor, it should work. I am working on modulating the transmitter. What would you prefer for receiver circuit?

Comment: I will work on the circuit shortly when I'm next near a PC. I assume you want the receiver to work from a single 9v source as well? What voltages will it have available? And do you want the final signal to be read by a microcontroller? (In which case I assume there's a 5v supply rail available  and that the final signal needs to be digital 0-5v?

Comment: @user5311361 I'd use photodiodes with a similar spectral response to the laser frequency. I might even consider adding a light filter to block the blue end of the spectrum, assuming you are using a red laser.

Comment: @Jodes Sure. Thank you. I was able to modulate at 1 kHz and 2 kHz. I am having trouble with the sensor circuit. It has to be a higher frequency because as per the object speed and size, the object would be for at least 12ms in front of the sensor laser beam. Yes. I would have 9 volts source ( therefore, we can get any volts between 0-7 using a buck converter). I want to be used with a 5 volts microcontroller. You are right. The logic would be 5 (HIGH) and 0 V (LOW).

Comment: @Trevor Okay, great. I am trying to build the circuit right now. I should try with the photodiodes too. Would a bunch of IR LEDs help? What do you think?

Comment: @Jodes I have updated the laser information in the question.

Comment: @user ok, great. So 1kHz is OK though? (10 cycles or more would be ideal for detection, so fits within your 12ms, unless I misunderstood?). Also, will the system have to cope with direct sunlight? Your ambient sensor's specs suggest it cannot distinguish above 1000 lux and direct sunlight is 100k+. What model is your photodiode? (Would you be happy with an alternative?)

Comment: @Jodes Yeah, 1 kHz is good enough I guess. 10 cycles should be able to detect the absence. I have one RadioShack Photodiode and one other photodiode ( I don't know the model). Sure, please suggest some alternative (cost effective :) ).

Comment: I just bumped into a circuit that might do what you want! It looks excellent to me - and it's obviously been tested properly - how does it look to you? http://www.discovercircuits.com/H-Corner/40khzlight.htm - just feed the output of the final op-amp into the MCU and ignore the rest of it (ie the 12v rail, diode, resistor and transistor). Just a couple of resistors need changing so it works at the lower frequency (if you want! But if you can modulate the laser to 40hKz then use it as-is!) What do you think?

Comment: @Jodes First of all, thank you so much. I don't know why but stackexchange did not show me the notification about your comment. The circuit looks promising. But, I could not understand the use of inductors and Darlington transistor. I don't have MPSA13, but I do have TIP31, TIP120 etc. I don't know it would work or not. Secondly, which resistors would help me reduce the frequency?

Comment: @Jodes I should try this in coming week.

Comment: Any small signal NPN transistors should be fine - they just need a DC current gain (aka beta value, or hfe) of 100 or more. Multiplied this gives 10,000 which is that of the MPSA13. (TIP31 for example is only about 25). I'll take a closer look at the circuit and see how best to reduce the frequency. I'm rusty on inductors myself so will play it by ear; I might simplify the circuit to help all involved! I'll get it working on circuitlab so it can be played around with.

Comment: Okay, sure. I will try to find some equivalent transistors around and then try it out.